# Nifi jolt transformation to transform input json

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

Can someone help me on defining jolt specification to transform input json to Output json for below json ..I have input json in a file as few json objects like {"filename":"test1","value":"10"} {"filename":"test2","value":"10"} . Transformed Output json should be like below  : {"filename":"test","overallvalue":"20", "filename":[{"filename":"test1","value":"10"},{"filename":"test2","value":"10"}]}

Filename and Overall value bith I am getting some other fields so can pass as parameter to the jolt specification

Comment: My input JSON will be like below

 

[ {

"filename":"test1.csv",

"message":"HiveSQL query executed Sucessfull!",

"status":"Success"
}, {
"filename":"test2.csv",

"message":"HiveSQL query executed Sucessfull!",

"status":"Success"
}, {
"filename":"test3.csv",

"message":"HiveSQL query executed Sucessfull!",

"status":"Success"
} ]

Comment: Output JSON should be like below  Output JSON should be : main_file,Overall_status,final_message will get values from flowfile attributes

{
"filename": "${main_file}",
"ex_status": "${Overall_status}",
"error": "${final_message}",
"fl_status": [
{
"file_name": "test1.csv.",
"status": "Success",
"message": "HiveSQL query executed Sucessfull!"
},
{
"file_name": "test2.csv",
"status": "Success",
"message": "HiveSQL query executed Sucessfull!"
},
{
"file_name": "test3.csv",
"status": "failed",
"message": "HiveSQL query executed Sucessfull!"
}
]
}

Comment: Please update your question with the JSON and use the code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jolt uses `\\` as escape character, since the data has `$` which is reserved character for jolt.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#\\${main_file}": "filename",
      "#\\${Overall_status}": "ex_status",
      "#\\${final_message}": "error",
      "*": "fl_status"
    }
  }
]
```